# Definition of $\mathscr{O}(n)$ on $\mathbb{P}_k^m$ does not depend on affine cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Ravi Vakil's Notes on Foundations of Algebraic Geometry. I'm confused by the remark following 14.1.B on page 198 in Nov1817 edition.

In particular, he mentioned that $\mathscr{O}(n)$ on $\mathbb{P}_k^m$ does not depend on affine cover and then asked questions: where does the section $x_0^3 - x_0 x_1^2$ of $\mathscr{O}(3)$ vanish? Which section do you get when multiplynig $x_0 + x_1$ in $\mathscr{O}(1)$ with $x_0^2$ of $\mathscr{O}(2)$?

To these questions my answer was:
(1) It vanishes at $[0: 1], [1: 1], [-1: 1] \in \mathbb{P}^1$;
(2) We get the section $x_0^3 + x_1 x_0^2$.
But I'm not sure why this demonstrate that the definition of $\mathscr{O}(n)$ does not depend on affine cover.

Thanks!

Comment: What is his definition of $O(n)$?

Comment: $\mathscr{O}(n)$ is the $n$-fold tensor power of the twisting sheaf $\mathscr{O}(1)$.

Comment: I think the point of the remark was not to demonstrate that $\mathcal{O}(n)$ doesn't depend on the choice of cover, but to demonstrate the utility of this, in that you have a simple description of the sections from which you can read off the zeroes with little effort.